# Android tab-menu switching pages without create new fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, tabs

i have got a problem with my tab-menu.
my menu hast got 3 pages, when the app start it shows the first page, but when i switch to the third and go back to the first, then the first page is created new. i know this in cause of a timer who is set to 00:00 after going to the third page 
now my problem is how can i fix this?

i have tried to check whether the object is null and when not then create a new else use the existing but it doenst work.

the complete code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private points points;
private teams teams;
private statistics statistics;


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

private String tabs[]= {"Punkte", "Mannschaft", "Statistik"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0: if(points == null) return new points();
                    else return points;
            case 1: if(teams == null) return new teams();
                    else return teams;
            case 2: if(statistics == null) return new statistics();
                    else return statistics;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return tabs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

what i tried:

```
        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0: if(points == null) return new points();
                    else return points;
            case 1: if(teams == null) return new teams();
                    else return teams;
            case 2: if(statistics == null) return new statistics();
                    else return statistics;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

thank you for your help =)

Comment: Do you use `ViewPager`?

Comment: yes i use one, i created this with android studio and i used the submission for this.

Comment: you should practice class naming conventions in Java as to [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947084/why-should-the-first-letter-of-a-java-class-be-upper-cased)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using the view pager for loading fragments,use

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Comment: This will work, but isn't it better to store state of ui with onSaveInstanceState and restore in in onRestoreInstanceState? You will not "waste" app memory for keeping fragments